# Elasticsearch query not returning expected results for multiple should filters

Tags: elasticsearch

I am performing an Elasticsearch query using the high-level-rest-api for Java and expect to see records that are either active or do not have a reference id.  I'm querying by name for the records and if I hit the index directly with /_search?q=, I see the results I want.

Is my logic correct (pseudo-code):

```
postFilters.MUST {
  Should {
    MustNotExist {referenceId}
    Must {status = Active}
  }
  Should {
    MustNotExist {referenceId}
    Must {type = Person}        
  }
}
```

What I get are records that are active with a reference id.  But, I want to include records that also do not have a referenceId, hence why I have MustNotExist {referenceId}.

For simplicity, the second Should clause can be dropped (for testing) as the first one is not working as expected by itself.

Comment: you can use multi match with OR operator

Comment: Would you mind sharing an example and posting an answer? I'll try it in the mean-time and see if I arrive at the same solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I had to use a match query instead of a term query because the value I was querying for was not a primitive or a String.  For example, the part where Must, type = Person, Person was an enum, and so looking for "Person" was not quite right, whereas match allowed it to "match".